# Top-align of tabular content

Tags: tables, align

How do I make the fields on the right (that should be top-aligned) aligned to the one on the left?

```
\begin{tabular}{r| p{\onethirdwidth}}
\cvevent{09.17--07.20\\Grade: X}{MSc in XXX}{University of Flatland}{Tortuga}{just text} \\
\end{tabular}
```

How it looks like: [image]

How I wish it looked like: [image]

**Edit 1**: I'm using this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pastel-cv/ygmdxppqvdyx

**Edit 2**:

The document class is pastelcv, defined in the link at **Edit 1**.

The command \cvevent is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\cvevent}[5]{{#1} & \textbf{#2}\newline\textsc{#3} $\cdot$ {#4 
~\faMapMarker}\newline{\color{black!70}\footnotesize #5}\vspace{1.5em}}
```

and the variable \onethirdwidth is given by

```
\newlength{\onethirdwidth}%
\setlength{\onethirdwidth}{0.33\textwidth}%
```

Comment: Could you please post a small , but complete and *compilable* code reproducing your problem?

Comment: Which document class do you employ? How or where are `\cvevent` and `\onethirdwidth` defined?

Comment: @Mico I've just edited the question, thank you in advance for your help!